# Bizarre NSSet copying crash

Tags: objective-c

I have a class that contains an `NSSet`.  That object is called `_collectibles`, and in a method, I make a copy of that set in order to do some processing, something like:

```
NSSet* collectibleCopy = [_collectibles copy];
```

In practice, I see this regularly crash with this message:

```
[__NSPlaceholderSet initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects
```

I've resolved the issue by changing the above code to:

```
NSMutableSet* collectibleCopy = [[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithCapacity: [_collectibles count]];
for ( id thing in _collectibles ) {
    [collectibleCopy addObject: thing];
}
```

And now I can no longer reproduce any such crash.  I'm betting `[copy]` is more efficient, and I'd rather use it, but I can't figure out why it's completely wonky!

Update: while full context would take a ton of explanation, the keys to me solving this were that, a, the code was invoked this way:

```
NSBlockOperation* operation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock: ^{
   [thing doStuff];
}];

[operationQueue addOperation: operation];
```

And that I was, basically by making a bunch of things slower, catch the app with 2 threads running 2 threads for a queue initialized thusly:

```
operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;
```

Which I thought impossible.  The clue was that the second thread was in [NSAutoreleasePool drain], which led me to learn that NSOperationQueue can do autorelease stuff whenever/however it wants.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce your bug. Could you post a bit more code for context?

Comment: is the set that you are copying a core data relationship?

Comment: The entire context would require a huge pile of code. :)

Answer (score 2):

Would

```
NSSet* collectibleCopy = [NSSet setWithSet:_collectibles]
```

work for you?

Comment: It might have- I'm guessing the reason it didn't crash (see my other answer) was something about the semantics of fast iteration vs. whatever NSSet does for the NSCopying protocol.

Answer (score 2):

OK, so huzzah for having actually figured this out.

The trick here was that this operation was performed on an async `NSOperationQueue`.  TIL that NSOperationQueues have AutoreleasePools, but that they get drained at the discretion of GCD.  In this case, the pool from a previous operation was being drained on another thread concurrently, causing what amounts to a rather opaque concurrent modification problem.

Solution:

`@autoreleasepool` inside the block on which this code got invoked.  This causes the drain to happen as part of the block, rather than asynchronously, and my race condition goes away.